# Is it possible to remove bounty related badges and reports from the Meta?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounty

An interesting thing I noticed the other day was that when someone was rattling off all the requirements to post a bounty, one of them was "Not on a Stack Exchange 2.0 Meta". Which, in glancing, is true - you cannot post a bounty no matter how high your invisible reputation is, nor is your reputation on the parent site useful for it. I don't really mind this as it really makes sense.

But I've got a little nag on my profile telling me to consider posting a bounty on an open question of mine. Which I can't do. And likewise, we have Altruist, Benefactor, Investor, and Promoter on the Meta when it's impossible to attain them.

I realize that actually changing the profile thingadongdong and changing the actual badge listing on the Meta sites is a lot more complicated than just adding a conditional to when you can start a bounty. **So this is a low-priority feature-request**. But, if it isn't too much trouble to implement at some point in the future, it would certainly help stave off the occasional confusion.

Comment: shouldn't this be on meta.SO since it will concern all betas?

Comment: @Tobias I considered that. But the whole placement of where these go is still being fought back and forth. What I do know is that whether or not this would fit better on Meta SO, it concerns this site very much more, so it is still rather fitting here. At least, that's my logic of operation right now. Oh, and you probably meant "all metas".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I've got a little nag on my profile telling me to consider posting a bounty on an open question of mine. Which I can't do.

Good point, I checked in a change to disable that message on child metas

> And likewise, we have Altruist, Benefactor, Investor, and Promoter on the Meta when it's impossible to attain them.

True, you'll note there is no Beta badge here either. I'll look into removing these tomorrow.

Comment: Huh, I actually didn't notice that the Beta badge wasn't listed. I think it might've been around at the very early stage of the private beta, but I never noticed it was removed. That means it's a lot easier for you than I thought - which is great! Thanks, Jeff!